# getting `undefined symbol: _PyObject_NextNotImplemented` error when trying to run Numpy.Net on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: .net, numpy, f#

I wanted to try Numpy.Net with F# using anaconda environment on Ubuntu 18.04.3 with VS Code.

First I created a new conda environment `conda create --name fsharp371 python=3.7.1`

Then `conda activate fsharp371` and `pip install numpy=1.16`

Init the project via `dotnet new console -lang "F#" -o NumpyTest`

then `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/hnc/.conda/envs/fsharp371/bin"`

and `dotnet add package Keras.NET.Mono --version 3.7.4.1`

My code is very simple:

```
// Learn more about F# at http://fsharp.org

open System
open Numpy

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let arr = Numpy.np.array [|10;20;30|]
    printfn "Hello World from F#!"
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

However, with `dotnet run`, I am getting:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Exception: dlsym: /home/hnc/Documents/github/NumpyTest/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/NumpyTest: undefined symbol: _PyObject_NextNotImplemented
   at Python.Runtime.NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(IntPtr dllHandle, String name)
   at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Initialize(Boolean initSigs)
   at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize(IEnumerable`1 args, Boolean setSysArgv, Boolean initSigs)
   at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize(Boolean setSysArgv, Boolean initSigs)
   at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize()
   at Numpy.np.InstallAndImport(Boolean force)
   at Numpy.np.<>c.<.cctor>b__599_0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Numpy.np.get_self()
   at Numpy.np.get_int32()
   at Numpy.DtypeExtensions.GetDtype(Object obj)
   at Numpy.np.array[T](T[] object, Dtype dtype, Nullable`1 copy, String order, Nullable`1 subok, Nullable`1 ndmin)
   at Numpy.np.array[T](T[] data)
   at Program.main(String[] argv) in /home/hnc/Documents/github/NumpyTest/Program.fs:line 13
```